# Nginx redirect http to https not working

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm setting up an nginx server with an SSL.

The domain with the ssl is dev.cooknconnect.com
  I want to redirect all requests from: http://domain.com to https://domain.com
  I have the following server blocks setup currently:

```
server {
         listen      1.2.3.4:80 default;
         server_name domain.com;
         server_tokens off;
         rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        }
 server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
            keepalive_timeout   70;
            server_tokens off;
            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/certificate.key;
            ssl_session_timeout 5m;
            ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
            ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass  http://domain.com;
            }

         }
```

This currently does not work, but I don't understand why not.Can anyone find any mistake in my config.If not please suggest some way to track or debugging the same.

Comment: Why it's `listen IP:80` and not `listen 80`?

Comment: Initially I tried with "listen 80".But that time nginx was not restarting.

Comment: What error did nginx report?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `"RC4+RSA"` - ouch! RC4 is broken for use in TLS, and RSA key transport does not provide forward secrecy (the IETF is deprecating it in TLS 1.3). `"+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP"` - daggers in my heart....

Comment: [Configuring HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) from the nginx docs might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this and it should work normally

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

keep in mind that `https://dev.yourdomain.com` won't work, because your certificate was issued only for the root domain, the https for the dev subdomain will show the yellow certificate warning.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name *.example.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This will permanently rewrite http to https for the domain itself and sub-domains to https mode.